# Is there an proof search functionality for F*?

Tags: fstar, fstar-mode

As we know, we have "auto" (proof search) in Agda (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> in Emacs) as well as Idris as well as Coq, but when I was digging into F*'s Emacs mode, I failed to find a similar functionality.

Does F* have this feature? If so, how can I use it?